# Returning different outputs based on function caller

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to return either an array or object magically, depending on how the user calls the data.

Right now, it's a flat array (below), and if the user calls it like an object I'd like to return it as an object not an array, is this possible?

```
// array
$arr = ["data" => [], "time" => time()];
```

Proposed way to call as array:

```
$caller["data"] = array();
```

However, if I wanted the same logic from an object standpoint **without** casting it in my caller?

```
$caller->data = array();
```

Is this possible to do magically? (eg, reflection to look it up?)

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are actually asking here! Can you provide a better example please

Comment: You could create a class that implements the [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface. Then you can use it as an array to add/get data: `$foo['bar'] = []` or as an object: `$foo->bar = []`, if that is what you mean. Then you will also get them from different methods so you could actually make one return an array and another an object. It would be a bit weird though. It's better to be consistent in your class and casting it when it's used instead.